# ¿Qué es una "chapara"?

Tags: definiciones, méxico

La palabra suena como "chapara" o quizá "chaparla" y el contexto es una mujer. Mi conjetura es que tiene algo que ver con chuparla, quizas.

No encontré una palabra "oficial" que cumpla con el contexto de ha pasado algo sexual con la [chapara](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/chapara).

La duda me surge en este contexto: Un muchacho y una muchacha pasan tiempo solos en un cuarto, y alguien quiere saber si algo pasó. Él le pregunta:

> Qué pasó anoche con la "____".

Está en México, y a pesar de vivir aquí el dialecto de algunas es para mí un lenguaje diferente y inescrutable comparado con las grabaciones donde aprendí español y que entiendo casi como el inglés.

Comment: Por favor danos más contexto, como una frase donde se use o el país donde lo escuchaste. Me suena a "chavala".

Comment: @rodrigo Debe ser chavala! Una muchacho y muchacha pasan tiempo solos en un cuarto, y alguien quiere saber si algo pasó. Ella dice "qué pasó anoche con la "____". Está en mexico, y a pesar de vivir aquí el dialecto de algunas es a mí una lenguaje diferente y inescrutable comparado a las grabaciones donde aprendí español y que entiendo casi como inglés.

Comment: ¿Puede ser *chaparra*?

Comment: @rsanchez si, es muy posible. Ella es bajita y un poquito regordete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En México la palabra *chaparra* significa pequeña, enana, de baja estatura.

También hay novios que le dicen *chaparra* de cariño a su novia.

Comment: No es solo en Méjico: dle: [*chaparro, rra*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8ZwO9LE) | damer: [*chaparro, -a*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chaparra) (Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, PR; Bo; CR)

Comment: Qué buena la referencia, gracias murcielago09z por la respuesta y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Esperamos verte con frecuencia